# Angular Horizontal Text Carousel (without ext lib)

Tags: angular, carousel

I need your help to develop a horizontal text carousel (without lib like angularUI, material, etc..).

[Here is a Project Stackblitz Angular example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-z7vowe?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.scss)

In this photo i can slide the different style (Popular, Bohemian, ..) and the navigation text move on left to right and right to left. So how can do that please ?

[image: Result wanted]

```
<div class="carousel-container">    
    <ul class="search__filter__list" #categoryList>
        <li 
            *ngFor="let cat of categories; let i = index" 
            drag-scroll-item 
            (click)="setCurrentCategory(cat.label)" 
            [ngClass]="{ 'isActive': cat.label === currentCategory }"
        >
          <span class="search__filter__title">{{ cat.label }}</span>
          <span class="search__filter__icon">
            <i class="{{ cat.icon }}"></i>
          </span>
        </li>
      </ul>
  </div>

export class FilterCarouselComponent {
  currentCategory string = 'All;
  @ViewChild('categoryList', { static: false })
  categoryList!: ElementRef;

  categories: CategoryFilters[] = [
    {
      label: 'All',
      icon: 'fa fa-star',
      category: 'All',
    },
    {
      label: 'CSS',
      icon: 'fa fa-star',
      category: 'CSS',
    },
    {
      label: 'JS',
      icon: 'fa-brands fa-js',
      category: 'JS',
    },
    {
      label: 'React',
      icon: 'fa-brands fa-react',
      category: 'React',
    },
    {
      label: 'Angular',
      icon: 'fa-brands fa-angular',
      category: 'Angular',
    },
    {
      label: 'Sass',
      icon: 'fa-brands fa-sass',
      category: 'Sass',
    },
    {
      label: 'NodeJS',
      icon: 'fa-brands fa-node-js',
      category: 'NodeJS',
    },
  ];

  constructor(
    public darkModeService: DarkModeService,
    private scroll: ViewportScroller
  ) {}

  setCurrentCategory(category: string) {
    this.currentCategory = category
  }

  onWheel(event: WheelEvent): void {
    if (event.deltaY > 0) this.scrollToRight();
    else this.scrollToLeft();
  }

  scrollToLeft(): void {
    console.log('test');
  }

  scrollToRight(): void {
    console.log('test 2');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I add a new answer to show how make a "scroll drag" using a directive.

It's a bit complex because we need pay atenttion to diferent events (mousedown, mouseup, mousemove and touchdown,touchup and touchmove

The idea:join the mousedown and touchdown using "merge" in an unique subscription (idem with mousemove and touchmove, and idem with mouseup and touchmap)

For this simply use, e.g.

```
  merge(
      fromEvent(this.elementRef.nativeElement, 'mousedown'),
      fromEvent(this.elementRef.nativeElement, 'touchstart').pipe(
        map((event: any) => event.changedTouches[0])
      )
  )
```

This "observable" return an object with the properties of "MouseEvent".

We subscribe to mousedown, when mousedown make a switchMap to listen mousemove until mouseup happens.

We should pay attention to "not select" the item (else always "drag" we select the element from drag)

For this, when mouseup, we check if the delta is greater than a value. if it's is less than, e.g. 10, we emit an event. The value to emit can be the html element we are "dragging", but this makes impossible control the emiter. So we emit the child element of the "menu". So we can get, e.g. an attribute of this element to know what element is clicked

```
@Output() select:EventEmitter<any>=new EventEmitter<any>()
  constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef) {}
  ngOnInit() {
    this.subscription = merge(
      fromEvent(this.elementRef.nativeElement, 'mousedown'),
      fromEvent(this.elementRef.nativeElement, 'touchstart').pipe(
        map((event: any) => event.changedTouches[0])
      )
    )
      .pipe(
        switchMap((touchIni: any) => {
          return merge(
            fromEvent(this.elementRef.nativeElement, 'mousemove'),
            fromEvent(this.elementRef.nativeElement, 'touchmove').pipe(
              map((event: any) => event.changedTouches[0])
            )
          ).pipe(
            takeUntil(
              merge(
                fromEvent(document, 'mouseup'),
                fromEvent(document, 'touchend').pipe(
                  map((event: any) => event.changedTouches[0])
                )
              ).pipe(
                tap((touchEnd)=>{
                  if (Math.abs(touchEnd.pageX - touchIni.pageX)<10)
                  {
                    const item=(([...this.elementRef.nativeElement.children] || []).filter(x=>x.contains(touchEnd.target)) ||[null])[0]
                    if (item)
                      this.select.emit(item)
                  }
                }))
          ),map((touchEnd: any) => {
            return {
              touchIni: touchIni,
              touchEnd: touchEnd,
            };
          })
        )
        })
      )
      .subscribe((res: any) => {
        const incX = res.touchEnd.pageX - res.touchIni.pageX;
        const incY = res.touchEnd.pageY - res.touchIni.pageY;
        this.elementRef.nativeElement.scrollBy({
          left: this.direction!='vertical'?-incX:0,
          right:this.direction!='horizontal'?-incY:0,
          behavior: "smooth",
        });
      });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.subscription && this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }
```

This directive works like

```
  <ul class="carousel-container" #menu swiper-scroll (select)="select($event)">
    <!--see that we add an attribute "data-item" 
        where store the cat.label-->
    <li
      [attr.data-item]="cat.label"
      *ngFor="let cat of categories; let i = index"
      [ngClass]="{ isActive: cat.label === currentCategory }"
    >
      <span class="search__filter__title">{{ cat.label }}</span>
      <span><i class="{{ cat.icon }}"></i></span>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

in select

```
  select(el:HTMLElement)
  {
    this.currentCategory = el.getAttribute('data-item');

  }
```

The [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-jedqbb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.scss,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fswipper.directive.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to achieve the selection with the left arrow and right arrow, then, you could add an event for these HTML elements and handle the selection logic like the following:

```html
<section class="container" id="filter">
  <!-- forward() for click event  -->
  <div class="arrow left" (click)="forward()">
    <i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i>
  </div>

  <div class="carousel-container">
    <ul class="search__filter__list" #categoryList>
      <li
        *ngFor="let cat of categories; let i = index"
        (click)="setCurrentCategory(cat.label); indexSelected = i"
        [ngClass]="{
          isActive: cat.label === currentCategory && indexSelected === i
        }"
      >
        <span class="search__filter__title">{{ cat.label }}</span>
        <span><i [class]="cat.icon"></i></span>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <!-- backward() for click event  -->
  <div class="arrow right" (click)="backward()">
    <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>
  </div>
</section>
```

**component.ts**

```js
@Component({...})
export class Component {
 ...
 ... 
 indexSelected = 0;
 
 forward(): void {
    if (this.indexSelected > 0) {
      --this.indexSelected;
      this.setCategory();
    }
  }

  backward(): void {
    if (this.indexSelected < this.categories.length - 1) {
      ++this.indexSelected;
      this.setCategory();
    }
  }

  private setCategory(): void {
    const label = this.categories[this.indexSelected].label;
    this.currentCategory = label;
  }
}
```

Here's the [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-rkpebd?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: Thanks to achieve the selection with the left and right arrow !

Answer (score 0):

When we have this kind of menu, the only is put all the "categories" under a div with `overflow: hidden;` and use the javascript method [scrollBy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollBy)

I simplify a bit your .html

```
<section class="container" id="filter">
  <!--on click call to the function scrollTo pass as argument
      the template reference variable "menu"
  -->
  <div class="arrow left" (click)="scrollTo(menu, -1)">
    <i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i>
  </div>
  <!--see the template reference variable "menu" -->
  <ul class="carousel-container" #menu 
    <li
      [attr.data-item]="cat.label"
      *ngFor="let cat of categories; let i = index"
      [ngClass]="{ isActive: cat.label === currentCategory }"
    >
      <span class="search__filter__title">{{ cat.label }}</span>
      <span><i class="{{ cat.icon }}"></i></span>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <!--on click call to the function scrollTo pass as argument
      the template reference variable "menu"
  -->
  <div class="arrow right" (click)="scrollTo(menu, 1)">
    <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>
  </div>
</section>
```

The .css

```
.container{
  padding:1rem 0;
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap:nowrap;
  justify-content:start;
  align-items:center;
  width:100%;
}
.carousel-container {
  color: $black2;
  display:flex;
  column-gap: 1rem;
  flex-grow:1;
  margin:0;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-left:1rem;
}
li {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  gap:.5rem;
  padding:.15rem .5rem;
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid #f2f2f2;
  border-radius: 35px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  cursor: grab;
  &:hover {
    border: 1px solid silver;
  }
}
```

The function scrollTo simply use the scrollBy method of an element

```
  scrollTo(element:HTMLElement,direction:number)
  {
    element.scrollBy({
      left: (direction*200),
      behavior: "smooth",
    });
  }
```